# How to use lsim in matlab for a closed loop system

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory, matlab

I have designed a system using a minimum realization.

I have the A, B, C matrices and I have assigned closed loop poles for the system.

I used the place command to find my K matrix.

I am wondering if it is possible to use the lsim matlab command to simulate my closed loop system (A-B*K)?

$$x' = Ax+Bu$$
$$u=-Kx$$
$$x' = (A-BK)x$$
$$y=Cx$$

All examples I have found for lsim use the system transfer function or the open loop system.

I have seen examples such as this:

```
t = 0:0.01:10;         % simulation time = 10 seconds
u = zeros(size(T));    % no input
x0 = [0.1 0.1 0.1];    % initial conditions of the three states
sys= ss(A,B,C,D);
lsim(sys,u,t,x0)
```

But I am not sure how to use this with the closed loop (A-B*K) system.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can using the [`feedback`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/feedback.html) command. However, if your open-loop system is defined by your state-space system `sys= ss(A,B,C,D)`, then your closed-loop system would be defined as follows (and not by `A-B*K` as you suggest):

```
CL_loop = feedback(sys,K); % K is your controller/compensator, this needs to be an LTI object
lsim(CL_loop,u,t,x0); % you might have additional states due to the feedback loop, and so would need additional IC
```

Note that you may also need to change your input vector, as it's now representing your desired trajectory.

**Update after comment & question edit**

I think it's just a matter of creating a new state-space representation with the appropriate matrices, e.g.:

```
CL_loop = sys(A-B*K,zeros(size(B)),C,zeros(size(D))); % implement x'=(A-B*K)*x & y = C*x
lsim(CL_loop,u,t,x0);
```

Comment: Thank you for reading! This seems to still not be exactly what I am looking for, as the feedback that I would like is u=-K*x. I think what you provided would give u =-K*y.

Comment: I have updated my answer based on the extra information you provided in the question, I think it's just a matter of constructing a state-space system with the right matrices.